# Dump PostgreSQL without DROP DATABASE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I want dump a database, but, without DROP DATABASE, and CREATE DATABASE instructions, in .backup / .sql (generate file).

Actually I use this command:

```
pg_dump --format=c --no-privileges --no-owner --file=/tmp/`hostname`-`date +%d%m%Y`.backup --username=admin --host=127.0.0.1 database_name
```

But, in top lines of file, I have this:

```
DROP DATABASE...
CREATE DATABASE...
```

So, I my case, I want duplicate this database, and, if I use this script with **pg_restore** I drop the other database (I don't want that).

Comment: I think `DROP DATABASE` is included only when you use both `-c` and `-C` options on pg_restore. As far as I can tell, pg_dump *never* includes `DROP DATABASE`.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of pg_restore (which you'll have to use because you created a pg_dump with format=custom) is that if you supply the `--dbname=...` flag you will restore into that database (without dropping it).

If you supply the `--clean` command the db and objects will be dropped before being recreated.

If no `--dbname=...` flag is supplied, the creation commands will spool to stdout, which you can redirect to a file and load using psql.

To test, try:

```
pg_dump --format=c --no-privileges --no-owner --file=/tmp/`hostname`-`date +%d%m%Y`.backup --username=admin --host=127.0.0.1 database_name

pg_restore your_dump_file > createdb.sql

psql -d database_name -U postgres -f createdb.sql
```

Comment: I'll test that.

Answer (score -2):

Try below example, omitting the '-c' flag in `pg_dump` command:

```
pg_dump -C database_name | xz > backup-$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d).sql.xz
```

Answering comments (not sure if this is the best way to do it):

> can you explain what that does exactly?

Performs a dump of the database and compress it to a file named with the current date

> OP didn't have a -c or -C flag, and it was a custom format dump. I don't see how your answer contributes anything useful.

Well my answer tries to provide a solution to the post title, which is: `Dump PostgreSQL without DROP DATABASE`. If there are additional requirement to OP question, worth editing the post title.

Comment: can you explain what that does exactly?

Comment: OP didn't have a `-c` or `-C` flag, and it was a custom format dump. I don't see how your answer contributes anything useful.